# C++ Fake class with callbacks

Tags: c++, unit-testing, callback, tdd

What would be a good design pattern if I require to test a C++ class A which interfaces with class B where calls to B initiate callbacks to A later on?
I require complete control over these callbacks - when they are executed and with what information.

I'm using [Google Test](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/) and [Google Mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) as my testing frameworks. In Google Mock's intro, they explain the [difference between a fake and a mock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/ForDummies#What_Is_Google_C++_Mocking_Framework?). It seems I require a fake B class and not a mock.
In their docs they detail how to have [non-trivial implementations of B's functions](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/V1_5_CookBook#Delegating_Calls_to_a_Fake), but this does not solve my requirement of controlling callbacks from B to A.

**UPDATES:**

- Just to clarify: A has the callbacks. Some time after A calls B's functions, B  initiates callback functions in A. Although it doesn't matter how exactly, in my case B holds a pointer to A and calls a predefined interface function (derived from a pure virtual class A_abstract).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`class A` should not be concerned if the callback calls are made by `B` or by some completely different code, as long as all the information provided in the callback is correct.

This means that, if your testcase can obtain all the information needed for the callback, then you can invoke the callback from within the test script at the appropriate time and use a mock for `class B`.

---

If `class A` actually checks that the callbacks are performed by `class B` (in so far that can actually be achieved), then classes `A` and `B` are coupled too tightly to test them separately. Then you should rethink if they really should be two tightly-coupled classes.

Comment: You're first half seems to be the solution, I still need to test it. For some reason I was locked on the idea that B must trigger A. At least in my case it really doesn't matter if B or the test script calls A's callbacks.

Comment: That is how it always should be. And just remember that mocks don't have to resenble the real code, as long as the code-under-test can't notice or doesn't care about the difference.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question well, but it seems that what you desire is [the strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). You can achieve callbacks from B to A as long you have a A_abstract pointer as a member variable in B.

```
class A_abstract {

public:
    virtual void work() = 0;
};

class B {

private:
    A_abstract* _m_A_ptr;

public:
    set_a_ptr(A_abstract* _APtr) { _m_A_ptr = _APtr; }

    void work() {  _m_A_ptr->work(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Qt's (or someone else's) signals and slots? I like reasoning about signals and slots much more than callbacks, even though (I think) they are basically equivalent in functionality.

-Brian-

Comment: Nothing wrong with callbacks, but QT's signal and slots have different functionality. They very similar to Publisher/Subscriber pattern., but little worse because of the way QT registers callbacks.